# How to select a objects, using it's children's array value..?

Tags: jquery, arrays, underscore.js

In my array, i am getting multiple objects, Each of the object contains number of child nodes, in which there is a child having a array with children's, using that array children's value how can i get the object what i am required..?

I am using underscore.js to get this, but i am not getting the value.. any one help me the correct approach to get what i described using uderscore.js please..

here is my sample and try :

```
var obj = [
    {
        name : true,
        deleted : false,
        updated : [
            {
                upStatus : true
            }
        ]

    },
    {
        name : true,
        deleted : false,
        updated : [
            {
                upStatus : false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name : true,
        deleted : false,
        updated : [
            {
                upStatus : false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name : true,
        deleted : false,
        updated : [
            {
                upStatus : false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name : true,
        deleted : false,
        updated : [
            {
                upStatus : false
            }
        ]
    }
]

    var hws = _.select(obj,function(val,key){    
        return val.updated.upStatus == false;
    });

    console.log (hws); // i am not getting any value. since i am not able to find the array value..
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yZcpe/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`_.find`](http://underscorejs.org/#find) or [`_.findWhere`](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) for children array, they both return on first satisfied entry and return `undefined` If no match is found, or if list is empty:

```
var hws = _.select(obj,function(val,key){    
    return _.find(val.updated, function(status) {
         return status.upStatus == false;
    })
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yZcpe/2/)

Comment: Don't call ppl who use "_.find or _.findWhere" kids :(

Comment: I didn't, sorry my poor english, better now? @ProblemFactory

Comment: It was just a joke, I am not native english speaker also, don't ask me :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `return val.updated[0].upStatus == false;` as `updated` property is an array you have to get its first element

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yZcpe/1/)

Comment: you are correct, but there is a chance to get multiple array values.. with different value

Comment: @3gwebtrain, You mean that `upStatus` shouldn't be `false` in entire `updated` array

Answer (score 0):

The `updated` property contains an *array of* objects, not a single object with that `upStatus` property. So use

```
function(val) {    
    return !val.updated.length || !val.updated[0].upStatus;
}
```

as the filter expression. If you need to check all objects in the array, use some kind of [`some`](http://underscorejs.org/#some) or [`every`](http://underscorejs.org/#every) check on them:

```
function(val) {    
    return _.some(val.updated, function(update) {
        return !update.upStatus;
    });
}
```

Comment: I have a change to get no.of array value as true and false.. I am looking for array loop here..

Comment: What predicate do you want? Every item whose `updated` array contains `false` `upStatus`es?

Comment: @3gwebtrain: Don't use `find` (of `findWhere`) if you're looking for a boolean result.